# Create an image.plot with white background (z), country contours and x/y points

Tags: r, image

I have this: 
[Air temperature map Europe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvpUH.png)

I made that image.plot with the following R code, where x, y, and z are each 385*373 grid point matrices. Longitude and Latitude are present as rotated coordinates.

```
temperature <- matrix(runif(143605,1,30), nrow = 385, ncol= 373) #Example data
berlin <- c(x = 13.4, y = 52.52)

image.plot(x = longitude, y = latitude, z = temperature, xlab = "Longitude", 
           ylab = "Latitude", main = model.names, col = heat.colors(10)) +  
  points(berlin["x"], berlin["y"], pch = 21, bg = "black") +
  data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = TRUE)
```

What I wish is the following:
Instead of a color ramp for the z values I want a simple white background! I don't want any z-data displayed. I only seek to have a white background with the country contours (wrld_simpl) and some points on it. I tried it with a NA matrix for z, but that didn't work. 
I suppose this should be easy to do, but I can't find any solution...thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Perhaps you may want to provide example data? [*more...*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/6574038)

Comment: I did so, hope it helps you helping me :) Longitude and Latitude have the same data structure as 'Temperature'.